# Assign GitHub project card to the specific user

Tags: github, project-management

I need to assign another user(or multiple users) to GitHub project card - can i do that directly, not by @username in the body of card? I've seen such feature on Trello, but not sure if it is possible on GitHub. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot assign 'note card' in Github project card.

- as already noted, workaround could be to mention @username in the body of the card
- or convert the *note card* to *github issue card* selecting '... -> convert to issue'.  The issue needs to be assigned to a git repository and then it can be assigned to a user or to multiple users.